# IE8 input css style and align

Tags: css, input, ie8-compatibility-mode

For testing purpose I have a basic form with three inputs aligned on the same line :

**"name"**(type=text), **"password"**(type=text) and **"submit"**(type=submit)**.

like this:

```
<body>
<form>
<input type="submit" class="search" value="log in"/> 
<input type="text" value="username"/>
<input type="text" value="username"/>
</form>
</body>
```

If I go **testing in IE8** switching the compatibility-view button i have my form shifting down-right and i noticed also the padding changes even if i apply a reset css like this:

```
<style>
html, body, span,a, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5,div, h6, p, blockquote, pre, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th,input, td {border: 0 none;margin: 0;padding: 0;
```

**How can someone achieve to have the form steady in the same position ,with all those three inputs aligned and also the padding the same while switching the compatibility-view button?**

thanks

Luca

Comment: Can you show the relevant CSS?

Comment: Why would you want that? You write your site for one "mode". Why would visitors switch to compatibility mode, when your site doesn't need it?

Comment: i don't have any I just have a bare document with this form for testing purpose and the css i posted is all i have in it

Comment: compatibility is not feigning an old browser view?? maybe i misunderstood its utility..

Comment: No "compatibility mode" is for the browser to render old (broken) websites. Since it's unlikely you want to create a broken website, you can ignore it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found myself an answer giving height and positioning the input type=submit as absolute..
it's a work-around

Answer (score 1):

I'm far from an expert with CSS and web page design, but I am currently struggling with updating a web application to look decently in IE 7 after developing and testing primarily with Chrome and IE 8.

I've been using compatibility mode in IE 8 to test page layout in IE 7;  from a cursory test with a virtual machine having IE 7 installed on it, compatibility mode renders a page as IE 7 does, and it reports itself to be IE 7.

As far as I can tell, the issue is that IE 7 just renders the input button to be taller than IE 8 does.  See an example with no css here:  http://jsfiddle.net/zHpX8/4/

If you add a style to explicitly set the input height, then it seems to render the same in both regular mode and compatibility mode:  http://jsfiddle.net/zHpX8/6/

Not an ideal answer, and I hope someone with more knowledge will provide a better one as I could use it as well.  Currently, for little things like this, I just live with it if it isn't too bad, but for the few cases where I can't find common ground, I have a style sheet specifically for IE 7, and one for all other browsers.

I wish IE 7 would just go away already...

Comment: and how did you choose the right height for the button? just by testing-and-checking ?

Comment: @luca, yeah trial and error, and I see what you mean.  It looks like IE 8 centers everything vertically and IE 7 aligns them along the bottom.  At this point, I would start experimenting w/ margin and/or padding to try and explicitly line things up.  It's a pain.

Comment: at least someone who's experimenting my same problem..looks like everybody else has the solution and dont wanna tell=)

Comment: @luca, as a side note, if you haven't seen this site, http://www.quirksmode.org/ is a good source of information for css browser compatibility.  Hope you get things working to your liking - good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Set a doctype on the html page like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

as the first line in the html document

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> ...this is right?? what do you mean??

Comment: as long as you have a valid doctype, the different versions of ie's render engine should behave similar. Most of the time using the simple doctype i wrote above (the html5 doctype which is perfectly backwards compatible) is enough

Comment: the problem is still there =(